# Is there a way I can prevent a function to be restored on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html

I know how to send a form without page refresh with jQuery. That is not what I'm about here. I just wanted to point that out. I have a button when `onclick()` will display a form and a hidden link. The problem I'm facing is when the form is being submitted the page refresh so the hidden link returns to initial state which is hidden.

Is there a way I can prevent a function to be restored on page refresh? That's what I'm interested to know. But if the best way to do this is by preventing the form to refresh I will do it. I just wanted to know if I could do it another way for knowledge sake. I'm trying to learn new ways instead of always doing same old jQuery stuff.

**html**

```
<button id="showOwn" type="button" onclick="showHiddenForm();" >
I'm a returning client</button>

<div id="hiddenForm" style="display:none;">

<form method="POST" action="form.php">
<input type="submit" name="validate_customer" value="Confirm Identity">
</form>

<a id="hiddenLink" href='other_page.php>Continue as Roger Rabbit</a>

</div>
```

**script**

```
function showHiddenForm(){
    //show hidden form
    document.getElementById("hiddenForm").style.display='block';
}
```

Comment: "_Is there a way I can prevent a function to be restored on page refresh_" Store a cookie value that indicates if you should execute the function or not and then check that value in your function?

Comment: @csm_dev: Purely client-side information should never be stored in cookies anymore. It was always a bad idea, it's just there wasn't an alternative until web storage. Now there is.

Comment: @csm_dev: I edited my question with new title.

Comment: You are right, when I say cookie I am thinking in my mind of whatever local storage is available, not exactly cookies _per-se_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use localStorage:

```
window.onload = () => {
 if( localStorage.getItem("show") )
  showHiddenForm();
};

function showHiddenForm(){
 localStorage.setItem("show",true);
//show hidden form
document.getElementById("hiddenForm").style.display='block';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I just wanted to know if I could do it another way for knowledge sake.

Store a flag in local storage (or session storage) ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)) and on page load, use the presence/absense of that flag to determine whether to hook up the function (or generally, to do whatever it is you want to do differently, differently).